# android xml file creation

Tags: android

i m working on a project in which i have to store and read some list elements in xml format i did the prasing part by creating file in res/xml and and using getResources().getXml(R.xml.SAMPLEFILE); it works well.. problem arise when i go for file creation..i m unable to find tutorial which lets u creat or open(if already created) xml in res/xml..

http://www.anddev.org/write_a_simple_xml_file_in_the_sd_card_using_xmlserializer-t8350.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add anything to your res folder during runtime. If you want the xml to be stored there you'll have to add it in when you compile. If you need it to be dynamic then you'll have to store the xml file in a different place.

One option you have is private internal storage for your application. [Check out this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)
for an overview of how to save to and read from this internal storage.